# What is causing slowness when pasting text to terminal emacs (emacs -nw)?

Tags: terminal-emacs, performance

For work, I run terminal emacs inside tmux on a remote server, which I access via PuTTY on a Windows machine. (So far, I haven't found a better way to pickup where I left off when editing remote code.)

The problem: Pasting text from Windows to emacs can be **painfully** slow, depending on lines of code. In my test, I'm copying to an empty `foo.c` so it loads `c-mode`, by default.

- 1-3 lines: instantaneous
- 4-6 lines: 0.5s delay
- 8-10 lines: 1-3s delay
- 11-12 lines: 4-6s delay
- 20 lines: 24s delay
- etc. exponential

I have eliminated PuTTY and tmux as culprits, so that leaves Emacs...

I tried the following:

1. Switch to `fundamental-mode` --> no change
2. Turn off `auto-save-mode` --> actually makes it worse, somehow
3. Turn off `undo-tree-mode` --> actually makes it worse, somehow

What could be causing this?

Is there a way to determine if Emacs is busy and, if so, with what?

Comment: Try running emacs -Q to see if the problem persists. Emacs can be configured to a surprising amount of work on each key press, and a paste can look like a lot of key presses arriving all at once. You might also make sure that bracketed paste mode is enabled, and that PuTTY supports it.

Comment: Running `emacs -Q` and pasting did not solve the issue. However, my searches for "bracketed paste" eventually led me to check my version of PuTTY.... 0.63.  I updated to latest (0.76) and my problems are in the rear-view mirror. Thanks for the response!